# how to call some one

Tags: android, call, android-manifest

I'm trying to call some one after i press a `Button`
I worked with this:

http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/how-make-phone-call-your-application

i have a problem when i am trying to add this in the manifest

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"></uses-permission>
```

My error is this:

> there should only be a single uses-sdk element in the manifest merge
>   these together

What do i need to do?

Comment: Check your manifest. Did you duplicate android:minSdkVersion attribute?

Comment: Show us your entire manifest file

Comment: im sorry i didnt noticed that i had another android:minSdkVersion ty for this and sorry for the stupid question.

Answer (score 0):

Search for duplicate `<uses-sdk>` tag in your `androidManifest.xml` file. You cannot have two elements of this tag. Removing one of them will solve the problem.